# How can i go back, forward and print a (local) WebBrowser1.DocumentText html page that's sourced from my.resorces - vb.net

Tags: html, css, vb.net, treeview, browser

the title basically says it, i have a from with a treeview and a webbrowser control and three buttons. i want the back button to load the previous viewed html file from myresources and the same but opposite for forward?... also how can i and where can i link my external css to my program like my.resources so when i export the program for installing on another machine it still works? and one more thing... how can i intergrate/embed the webbrowser control into my program because as i believe it uses internet explorer and if someone installs my program onto their computer and they have un-installed ie and use firefox it won't work? thank you guys very much, i know it's a lot of questions but you guys are awesome!. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easy for you if you read this web pages from the [resource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) file and then save them to a disk.

In this way you can simply pass the physical path to the [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate.aspx) method and similarly you can use [GoBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.goback.aspx) and [GoForward](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.goforward.aspx) and [Print](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print.aspx) methods.

But if you don't want them to save them, you still can read the web pages from the resource file and then use [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) property to display the webpage.

Using this method you won't be able to navigate back or forward.

Comment: Okay could you give me the code examples for exactly what you just said, or somebody else? thanks

Comment: @happycamper1221 I've already provided you the sample code. Click  on the resource link, you'll find a sample code over there and for accessing webbrowser control methods you just need to use object.methodname for example `WebBrowser1.GoBack()`

Comment: that's not really helpful 1. because some of it's in c# and i'm using vb.net (vb 2010) and 2. because it could take me hours to go through all that and it would just be more plain and simple seeing that I'm not an experienced programer if you could please provide the code examples customized to my situation. thank you